# Возникает ошибка с VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Работаю с движком и возникает ошибка:
при объявлении класса в заголовочном файле и сразу же при определении в этом классе всех методов, ошибки не возникает и всё компилируется. Но как только я определяю методы за классом, в отдельном файле cpp, или же ниже класса, то выдает постоянно ошибку. Никто не сталкивался с этим? На просторах интернета ничего не нашёл. VS13. Другой, как ни странно, не получится установить.
Скину скрины класса в заголовочном файле и файле cpp + скрин ошибку. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Оформите код в виде текста, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну так а этот "файл cpp" в проект добавлен?

Comment: AnT не знал, что cpp файл в проект добавлять нужно. Думал, что в папку с остальными файлами закину и всё. Сейчас добавил в проект и заработало. Спасибо.